# Substitute property of local variable in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I'm trying to write a simple Unit Test and have a problem with the mocking/substitutes.

The method I want to test looks like this:

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var openFileDialogViewModel = new OpenFileDialogViewModel
        {
            AddExtension = true,
            DefaultExtension = "xxx",
            Filter = "xxx Files|*.xxx"
        };

        bool result = mFileDialogService.OpenFile(openFileDialogViewModel);

        if (result)
        {
            mDatabaseLoadingService.LoadFile(openFileDialogViewModel.FileName);
        }
    }
```

For the test I want to set a filename, call the Execute method and check whether the file was loaded or not. In my test I used 'NSubstitute' to tell the 'OpenFile' method of my 'FileDialogService' to return true like this:

```
mFileDialogService.OpenFile(Arg.Any<IOpenFileDialogViewModel>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(true)
```

But how do I set the 'FileName' property of the 'OpenFileDialogViewModel'?

Comment: By consulting the documentation of your mocking framework and implementing a callback that assigns `modelParameter.FileName`.

Comment: You need to choose a way to inject the filename or the `OpenFileDialogViewModel`. Using the `new` keyword limits your options for outside interaction.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm using NSubstitute as mocking framework, but i cannot find a way to access the openFileDialogViewModel from my test.

Comment: @David it looks like the `mFileDialogService` is injected, and the call to `OpenFile()` is mocked.

Comment: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/

Comment: Thanks alot, if you post that link as an answer, I can mark it as correct answer ^_^

Comment: @CodeCaster: ah, I see now. I thought he/she wanted to set the `FileName` parameter on the `openFileDialogViewModel` prior to the call to `LoadFile()`.